# join two PIVOT table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query

```
With 
NoOfOrder as 
(
    SELECT  Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar
    FROM 
    (
        select LEFT(datename(month,InvoiceDate),3) mon,InvoiceNo as InvoiceNo
        from tbl_InvoiceMain ,tbl_OrderMain,tbl_CompanyMaster    
        where tbl_InvoiceMain.OrderID = tbl_OrderMain.OrderID
        and (CAST(tbl_InvoiceMain.InvoiceDate AS date) BETWEEN tbl_CompanyMaster.YearStart  AND tbl_CompanyMaster.YearEnd)
    ) P
    PIVOT (count(InvoiceNo)for mon in (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)) PV 
),
OnTime as
(
    SELECT  Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar
    FROM 
    (
        select LEFT(datename(month,InvoiceDate),3) mon,InvoiceNo as InvoiceNo
        from tbl_InvoiceMain ,tbl_OrderMain,tbl_CompanyMaster    
        where tbl_InvoiceMain.OrderID = tbl_OrderMain.OrderID
        and (CAST(tbl_InvoiceMain.InvoiceDate AS date) BETWEEN tbl_CompanyMaster.YearStart  AND tbl_CompanyMaster.YearEnd)
        and  CAST(tbl_InvoiceMain.InvoiceDate AS date) <= CAST(tbl_OrderMain.ScheduledDispatchDate AS date)
    ) P
    PIVOT (count(InvoiceNo)for mon in (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)) PV 
)
Select * From NoOfOrder
union all
Select * From OnTime
```

It gives this result:

```
Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Jan Feb Mar
18  35  39  52  32  47  47  22  14  0   0   0
9   10  16  22  6   11  19  10  5   0   0   0
```

Here is my expected result

```
                       Apr      May      Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec     Jan     Feb     Mar
NoOfOrder              18       35       39      52      32      47      47      22      14      0       0       0
OnTimeDelivered        9        10       16      22      6       11      19      10      5       0       0       0
DeliverPerformance%    50.00    28.57    41.03   42.31   18.75   23.40   40.43   45.45   35.71   0.00    0.00    0.00
```

The formula for DeliverPerformance is:

```
DeliverPerformance% = (OnTimeDelivered/NoOfOrder) X 100
```

How do I achieve this result on the next row?
for reference you check my question in good format
[enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/621b8c30-fdad-4566-9baf-1511fc4e268f/join-two-pivot-table?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 0):

My immediate suggestion is to combine everything first prior to pivoting the results.

Your first query might look like this:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(datename(month, InvoiceDate), 3) InvMon, 
    SUM(1) AS NoOfOrder,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(tbl_InvoiceMain.InvoiceDate AS date) <= CAST(tbl_OrderMain.ScheduledDispatchDate AS date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OnTimeDelivered
FROM tbl_InvoiceMain, tbl_OrderMain, tbl_CompanyMaster    
WHERE tbl_InvoiceMain.OrderID = tbl_OrderMain.OrderID
    AND (CAST(tbl_InvoiceMain.InvoiceDate AS date) BETWEEN tbl_CompanyMaster.YearStart AND tbl_CompanyMaster.YearEnd)
GROUP BY LEFT(datename(month, InvoiceDate), 3)
```

Note that I'm always counting every invoice record and optionally counting the "on time" invoices with that `CASE` statement and the respective `SUM` functions.

My next thought is to put that query in a CTE and then the statement that uses that CTE will do the additional calculation like so:

```
SELECT InvMon, NoOfOrder, OnTimeDelivered, ((OnTimeDelivered / NoOfOrder) * 100) DeliverPerformance ...
```

And finally, that's what I pivot.